# Opencart- order emails and enquiry form email ending up in admin's junk mail folder

Tags: smtp, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3

New order emails and enquiry form emails, both ending in admin's spam/junk folder. I am not able to rectify it. Using 'mail' configuration instead of 'smtp' in the console. Have put '-F' in front of mail parameters. Tried using the port '587', '465' for for smtp.office365.com. Need help!

Comment: Hi Sohail, this is likely not a result of the Opencart configuration. Have you set up DKIM authentication & SPF records for Office? Is the sender email address the same as the domain?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have created SPF and DKIM records. I am using sales@domain.com as the sender.

Comment: One other thing, you should be using "smtp" in the config if you want to use Outlook's smtp service, otherwise Opencart will use PHPMail

Comment: I tried with smtp, but after saving, it doesn't send emails. So I switched back to 'mail', so at least I get mails in the spam folder. Am I missing something very important here?

Comment: If it's being sent using "mail" then your website is sending out the email and that could be why it's being flagged as SPAM. Have you tried using a gmail account as the SMTP as a test? It seems like something in the config for O365 could be wrong.

Comment: While searching for the issue, I found someone made connectors in the admin panel of office365. It generated mx-records. Should I make another mx-record as the one we have in the account doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Why office365 doesn't ask for approval as Gmail asks for SMTP approval/verification?

Comment: It's difficult to determine what the exact cause of your problem is. Normally, incorrect MX records would affect delivery of mail in general, not necessarily incorrect classification of incoming mail as SPAM. I think you should reach out to the Office 365 support community, they're far better equipped to helping you if you're having domain / MX issues. There may be a simple solution

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, I'll try reaching them

Answer (score 0):

For those running into this issue with OpenCart here are some things you should verify.

Ensure your email address in System->Store->Email matches the email used in System->Mail->SMTP Username

In System->Mail->SMTP Hostname you may need to add the prefix "ssl://" or "tsl://" before your mail.servername.com this is not very clear and easy to miss if you're not sure which one to use, try ssl:// first then tsl:// and send yourself a test email with the contact form.

If using Cpanel, ensure there is an SPF record for your domain. This is found in Cpanel->Email->Email Deliverability

To test if emails are actually working the best way is to login into a test account and send a "Contact Us" email. If the page goes blank after submission, there is likely an issue with settings.

I have found using the OpenCart Default "Mail" setting will always result in emails being marked as spam, so you'll need to get in there and set them up with SMTP.